# $_POST outputs "striptag"

Tags: php, validation

I'm having a problem with $_POST which I really don't understand...
I have a form with a hidden input, value of the hidden input comes from database.

I am doing this:

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"reactie\" value=\"$naam\" />";
```

$naam is a variable which is assigned earlier:
note: subarray contains data from user reactions.

```
foreach($gegevens as $sub_array) {
     $naam = $sub_array['naam'];
}
```

When I just echo $naam, it gives me the value it should have.

When I want to get the value of the hidden input, it simply outputs 'striptag'.
When I watch the html code, the value of the hidden input is what it should be, and it's not 'striptag'.

output in html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="reactie" value="school" />
```

using this to get the value of the hidden input:

```
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    echo $_POST['reactie'];
}
```

When I put text in the value of the hidden input, it works. Why can't I put a string variable in it?

What I should get when I post the form, is "school", but what I get is "striptag".

Purpose of this form (in the end): list all user comments, when button is pressed, reaction will be deleted.
My whole form:

```
<form action = "guestadmin.php" method = "post">

<?php



include ('conData.php');
$sql = new ConData();
$sql->maakConnectie(); 
$gegevens = $sql->haalGegevensOp("select * from gastenboek");

foreach($gegevens as $sub_array) {
    $naam = $sub_array['naam'];
    $email = $sub_array['email'];
    $tekst = $sub_array['tekst'];
    $datum = $sub_array['datum'];

    echo "<div class = \"com\"> 
        <fieldset class= \"field\"> 
        <legend >Geschreven op $datum door $naam </legend>";

    echo "$tekst</fieldset>
        <input name = \"submitted\" type=\"submit\" 
            value = \"verwijder deze reactie\" /></div>";
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"reactie\" value=\"$naam\" />";
    echo "<br \>";
}
?>

</form>
```

If there was only one comment, this would output in html:

Geschreven op 2012-12-09 door Arnout
            dit is een test

I really don't understand

Comment: where is the value of $naam being assigned? Please post that portion of code.

Comment: Can you paste your html code for the input here? This would make things a bit clear. Paste all your related code here so that i makes others clear on the situation you are in.

Comment: Let's see a self-contained example, as small as you can make it. I'm almost certain it's an error on your part, not some random weirdness. Also, what exactly is in `$gegevens`, and why are you looping through each one when you are only assigning the last value?

Comment: $sub_array['naam'] is likely equal to 'striptag', Do echo $sub_array['naam'] to see it's value.

Comment: when I echo $naam, it's not equal to 'striptag', which is really strange..

Comment: If you really want to solve this, we need all the necessary code as well as the necessary data. Otherwise it's anyone's guess.

Comment: Are you using a PHP framework or sanitation class/function? Some will sanitize superglobals and replace the sanitized portion with what action was taken on the data.

Comment: Just an idea, is there another field on the page with the same name? Btw, you should check what is being sent to the server.

Comment: What does your packet sniffer say?

Comment: The string value "striptag" can't be coming from no-where. Try searching your codebase and any other sources to find reference to it.

Comment: my code doesn't contain the word 'striptag'. $sub_array is assigned by getting data from a database. when I echo $sub_array['naam'], it returns the value it should have and not 'striptag'.

Comment: Can you post the whole form? Perhaps you have another input with the name `reactie`.

Comment: I tried to reproduce all that you have supplied here except the sub_array thing and i am getting correct output.
@popnoodles well if $sub_array is giving the expected output, should we bother about the whole array?

Comment: The variables all contain the data they should contain . When I echo them, they all output the values they should have. So I it shouldn't be a problem with the assignment of the variables, right?

Comment: Check the value being posted using Firebug.

Comment: output when print_r($_POST):
    striptagArray ( [submitted] => verwijder deze reactie [reactie] => striptag )
problem seems to be the POST. But why would it change to striptag?

Comment: @popnoodles this is all of the code... I don't see what else I could post.

Comment: so it is. I think jeroen answered it. Can you post the outputted HTML of the entire form? I suspect there is a second `<input type="hidden" name="reactie"`

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 big problems:

1. All entries enter in the same form. That means you have multiple form fields with the same name, all overwriting each-other. You can solve that by placing the form-tag in the loop so that every entry has its own form;
2. You are not preparing your data for output to html. This means that `<`, `>`, etc. symbols in your data can and will break your html. You can solve that by using (for every data-field): `$naam = htmlspecialchars($sub_array['naam']);`.

Comment: Of course! Every entry should have their own form. Very obvious, thanks! This acually solved my problem.
As for point 2, true, but everything is already filtered before it is written to the database. So that shouldn't give problems :-)